# Hybrid bike inner tube size

Tags: tire, innertube, hybrid-bike

The following images shows the tyre sizes of my hybrid bike. I need to buy an inner tube with presta valve. I can't seem to figure out which size I should buy though. Can someone please point me to the right tube size for my bike?

[image: size info]

[image: size information]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your tire size is 700x38, meaning the overall width of the tire is 38 mm. Inner tubes are sold in ranges of sizes rather than for specific widths.

eg 700x23-25 - means this is suitable for 23 to 25 mm;
700x28-32 - suitable for 28 to 32 mm;
700x35-42 - suitable for 35 to 42 mm;
and so on. 
So you need to find a tube has your tire width (38 mm) that falls within the range that's on the packaging of the tube you're looking at. And make sure that it is with a Presta valve rather than Schrader.

Edit: just to be clear, the above ranges are just examples. Different manufacturers may have slightly different ranges.

Comment: From what you have explained, I found a couple of tubes with different ranges -https://bumsonthesaddle.com/collections/tubes/products/schwalbe-sv17-28-47-622-700x28c-45c https://bumsonthesaddle.com/collections/tubes/products/michelin-a3-protex-max-presta. Which one would you suggest?

Comment: The 700x28–45 you’ve linked is perfect for the 700x38 tire you have. Right in the middle of the range.